# Is it possible to set the Map iterator to a certain position in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections, iterator

Let's say I have a map: `Map<Int, String>` and I know how this map was created and that it preserves the order of iteration. How can I iterate on all elements in a given range?

```
val map: Map<Int, String> = mapOf(
    1 to "one", 
    2 to "two", 
    3 to "three", 
    4 to "four")

// Let's say I want to get all values after key 3.

val iterator = map.iterator()
while (iterator.next().key != 3) {}
val itemsAfter3 = iterator.asSequence().map { it.value }
```

Apart from being ugly, it is O(n). Is there an better, more elegant and efficient way?

I am thinking about doing something with `map.keys.indexOf()`, but it seems that here the complexity is linear too.

Comment: There's no support for this in the `Map`-interface, so you either have to use a different data structure or implement it using your Map-implementation class directly.

Comment: "it is O(n)" <-- Whether it can be done at a lower complexity depends on the map implementation though. Since you seem to know exactly how the map is implemented, are you sure the iterator can just jump around? It can't if the map is a `LinkedHashMap` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never rely on internal implementation, it may be changed in future. If you need a map preserving insert order during iteration, declare it explicitly:

```kotlin
val map: Map<Int, String> = linkedMapOf(
    1 to "one",
    2 to "two",
    3 to "three",
    4 to "four"
)
```

getting all values after specific index is easy as:

```kotlin
val valuesAfterIndex3 = map.values.drop(3)
```